# Python - modifying items in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of instances of a class A

```
class A:
def __init__(self,ox,oy):
self.x=ox
self.y=oy

list1=[A(3,0),A(5,0),A(7,3),......]
```

Now I need to find out the instance in the list which has y' as non-zero - and apply that value to all the other members in the list.
It is given that only one unique member will have y as non-zero.
With the usual for-loop we would need to iterate the list twice - with or without comprehension.
Is there a way to achieve this any better.
I have not used filter and map much but feel there may be a better option.
Help is appreciated.

Comment: What if there were multiple instances of `A` with `y` as non-zero?

Comment: in my solution I just "assumed" he wanted only the first one ...

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. At least two loops would be required no matter how it was implemented.

Comment: wouldnt my solution above only require a single iteration ?

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Of `a`, yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array([[3,0],[5,0],[7,3]])
zero_mask = a[:,1] == 0

a[zero_mask] = a[~zero_mask][0]
```

unfortunately it does not use your A class ...